# Remove multiple KVOs at one go

Tags: cocoa

Just looking for confirmation that there is no way to remove multiple KVOs at one go and that I have to issue separate

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name"];
```

for each observed key path (even if the observer is self). I've trawled the docs and SO without finding anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. There's no “builtin” method for removing multiple observers for multiple key paths.
But you could use categories to create your own methods, doing what you want:

```
@interface NSObject (ExtendedKeyValueObserving)
- (void)removeObserver:(NSObject *)observer forKeyPaths:(NSArray *)keyPaths;
@end
@implementation NSObject (ExtendedKeyValueObserving)
- (void)removeObserver:(NSObject *)observer forKeyPaths:(NSArray *)keyPaths {
    for (NSString *keyPath in keyPaths)
        [self removeObserver:observer forKeyPath:keyPath];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that JDS. I'll probably go with a variation on your suggestion.